# Microsoft Bluetooth Low Energy Advertisement

Tags: windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ads

While I'm performing a Bluetooth Low Energy scan, I faced two advertising packets that I don't understand. These two packets are respectively :

```
0x1eff060001092000f4a6326eb7f6dd2338b0b3502d434ffb6d5b89ae3082ab
```

and

```
0x1eff060001092000a6fac5c9f755e1fcdf29e6732d047c37825cd44aee744c
```

Reading the latest [Bluetooth Core Specification version 5.0](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification), it seems that these advertising packets are from Microsoft. Indeed, the structure of an advertising packet is [Length-Type-Value](https://www.silabs.com/community/wireless/bluetooth/knowledge-base.entry.html/2017/02/10/bluetooth_advertisin-hGsf) and, if I'm right, here I have:

- Length : `0x1e` in hexadecimal meaning "30 bytes" after decimal conversion
- Type : `0xff` meaning "Manufacturer Specific Data" (see [Bluetooth Generic Access Profile](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/generic-access-profile))
- Value : `0x060001092000a6fac5c9f755e1fcdf29e6732d047c37825cd44aee744c`

Analyzing the [structure of "Manufacturer Specific Data"](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/23406/rules-for-manufacturer-specific-advertisement-data) type, a company identifier is depicted in the first two bytes of the value. Here, the company identifier of the two advertising packets is 0x0600 (in big-endian). Converting it to little-endian (0x0006), I found "Microsoft" from the [Bluetooth assigned company identifiers](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/company-identifiers).

Actually, my questions are :

(1) Does anyone know what the `0x01092000f4a6326eb7f6dd2338b0b3502d434ffb6d5b89ae3082ab` part means ?

(2) Does anyone know how this particular type of advertising packet is triggered (by a Bluetooth enabled computer or other Microsoft hardware) ?

From what I've observed, the following schema of the *Value* can be derived:

- 1st part : `0x01092000`
- 2nd part : 23 bytes of data (for instance, `0xf4a6326eb7f6dd2338b0b3502d434ffb6d5b89ae3082ab`)

After having defined these two parts, I have no idea of what they represent...

Answer (score 1):

It's the advertising beacon described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt739556.aspx)

The first part 0x01092000 tells you that the sender is a Windows 10 Desktop (09) and the second part is a 4 random byte salt followed by a SHA256 hash of the device thumbprint.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Fanmen :). Actually, do you know what does "device thumbprint" mean here ? Is it its Bluetooth interface MAC address or an other serial number ?